# how to add devexpress to visual studio 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I downloaded the DevExpress Universal 12.2 Exe file, and that installs 2 folders to my computer. they are devexpress dxperience 12.2 and dxteeme 12.2 folders. When I open the visual studio express 2012, I cannot see the devexpress controls? I tried to repair my devexpress installation by clicking the SETUP.

What can I do to put devexpress tool box in visual studio.net 2012 ?

thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the Toolbox windows on Visual Studio, right click, select Chose Items. Then, browse your devexpress dlls, you can find these dlls on devexpress folders, select what dev controls you will need, like XtraGrid.dll, XtraEditors.dll, etc..

Comment: this is a little frustrating because there are many dll to select in the list but I think it is the easiest way. thank you

Comment: yeah yeah. But look if you gonna need all Dev controls. When i use it, most of the controls are on XtraEditors namespace and XtraGrid.

Answer (score 5):

These 2 knowledgebase article may help you as well:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/K18095.aspx
http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/KA18614.aspx

Comment: Yes, it does cost money to buy a license. It provides features, functionality, and a lot more too, learn more here: [DevExpress ASP.NET](http://devexpress.com/asp/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add them as a reference in your project. Just search for the .dll that was downloaded and add them to your project.